# What is wrong with the rabbit living under my shed?

Tags: animals, animal-behaviour, rabbits

[image]

So there is this rabbit that lives under my shed, and I've been watching it through my window for the past few days. It comes out in the mornings, and sits next to its hole crouched in a tight ball, and stays there until you approach. It lets you get within like 4 feet before it moves.  I have never seen it eat or move more than about 2 feet from the shed. I've left carrots, spinach, apple slices and such out next to its entrance, and those are untouched. Is it ill?  should I try to catch it to take it to a rehab? Should I euthanize it?

Comment: This was different, because it was originally a pet, but we had a rabbit escape and take up residence under our shed when I was a kid. It lived under there for years, no feeding or anything. I suspect this wild one can take care of itself.

Comment: Try seeds, especially oily seeds, I'd say a rabbit that doesnt'eat carrots and seeds on it's doorstep is acting weird.

Comment: We had a young wild rabbit spending some time on the lawn and surrounding properties. The only times I saw it eating was when a flock of birds landed to munch on seeds and stuff. Then it would relax and hop around among them eating.
The birds always had watchers that told them when any person or animal approached, and when the birds took off the rabbit would head for the bushes.

Comment: if someone left food on your doorstep would you eat it?

Answer (score 49):

The fact that you've never seen it eat doesn't mean it's not eating. That just means it doesn't eat while you're watching. Don't feed it. It's not a pet. It's a wild animal and will take care of itself.

Stop approaching it. When it knows you're watching it, and especially when you get close to it, you're causing it a lot of stress, because it thinks you're going to try to kill it.

Normally rabbits will graze near the entrance to their burrow so they can escape to safety if danger threatens. As they feel safer, they will venture further from the burrow entrance. If you are constantly watching it, you may be preventing it from feeding because it doesn't feel safe.

If you back off and leave the rabbit to its own devices, it may start grazing in your yard, which will allow you to enjoy watching it from a distance.

Comment: Of course "enjoy watching it" really depends on how much you like having a garden that's not gnawed bare :--(

Comment: @jamesqf We have a chicken wire fence to keep them out of our garden, about three feet high and bricks under it to keep the rabbit from digging under it.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a rabbit resisting a carrot? Put a carrot near it's burrow it is guaranteed to eat it unless it is sick. and seeds have so much carb, if it doesn't eat seeds it's probably not acting normal.

Comment: The rabbits I used to keep as pets weren't actually fond of carrots at all

Comment: @com.prehensible Despite popular myth, they don't actually care about the carrot at all, they care about the green leaves on top of the carrot (the plant, since the carrot is just the root of the plant).

Comment: These days, carrots have lots of nitter phosphates and nitrates from fertiliser in them. rabbits wouldn't go near them. I think they would go for organic ones though?!

Comment: It seems a lot of people are basing their ideas of rabbit behaviour on watching _Bugs Bunny_.

Comment: "you cause it a lot of stress, because it thinks you're going to try to kill it." - Well, that is exactly what "Should I euthanize it?" seems to be getting at. If the rabbit thinks that, it clearly isn't far wrong.

Answer (score 12):

[Rabbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit) are [crepuscular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular_animal) [coprophages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprophagia#By_vertebrates). That means they're most active at dawn and dusk so they're most likely to be eating their fresh greens when you're probably not looking because it's dark and when you do see them during the day, they'll probably be relaxing and chewing pellets.

The one in the picture looks like it's chewing pellets.  They don't need to move much because they, uh, ["produce" the pellets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit#Digestion) themselves.

I'd guess everything is normal here.  If you're really interested, set up a wildlife cam to try to catch its movements when you're not actively watching.

Answer (score 11):

The rabbit doesn't look like it's going hungry, so it's probably just not interested in what you're giving it.  [Rabbits favor grasses and leafy plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit#Digestion), so if you insist on feeding it, try something leafy like cabbage.

Comment: Having had pet rabbits, lettuce is really bad for their digestion (they get the runs). Cabbage and other brassica would be much better.

Comment: @IanF1, Thanks.  Updated.

Comment: Actually, cabbage is not the best choice.  [Are there specific vegetables I should not be feeding a rabbit?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/3115/13) Romaine or Green leaf are best.

Answer (score 6):

Rabbits are social creatures.

- Wild rabbits live in colonies/warrens, not alone.
- Where is the rest of the family?

So is this a pet that has escaped from a neighbour?

> I have been watching it for a few days.
>   Should I euthanize it?

*How?* and *Why?*
Just imagine, some kid gets to hear you used their pet for target practice.

So

- **Ask around:** has anyone has lost a rabbit?

Comment: This one appears to be an Eastern Cottontail, which is wild.